# Uncaught ReferenceError: ChangeSecondNavUlColor() is not defined - Javascript func not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Creating a WordPress website.

**Have a function `ChangeSecondNavUlColor()` that is called in the `header.php` to change the color of the `.menu-secondary-menu-links li a` (Navigation anchor tags color to white) IF user is not the front-page.php**

In the php code, I have an if statement to check if is on front page, if so I AM changing the background color of nav using echo $blackBg; but for the navigation a tag color (since it is nested), i've decided to grab the DOM using javascript.

But getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ChangeSecondNavUlColor is not defined

```
<header class="main-header">

    <div id="sidebar-btn">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>               
    </div>
<div id="sidebar-nav">              
    <div class="logo-nav-one-wrap">
        <nav class="nav-one">
            <li id="primary-headline" class="logo-icon"><img src="#"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></li>

            <ul>
                <?php 

                    $args = array(
                        'theme_location' => 'primary'

                    );
                    wp_nav_menu($args);
                ?>


            </ul>


            </nav>

    </div>

    <nav class="nav-two home-nav">
    <!--  CHANGE THE BACKGROUND COLOR OF NAV TO BLACK IF NOT HOMEPAGE -->
    <?php if(!is_front_page()) { 

        $blackBg =  "background-black-nav";  ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">  ChangeSecondNavUlColor(); </script>

    <?php } ?>
    <div class="nav-two-wrap <?php echo $blackBg;?>">

        <?php       
            $walker = new Nav_Walker_Nav_Menu;

            $args = array(
                'theme_location' => 'secondary',
                'walker' => $walker

            );
            wp_nav_menu($args);
        ?>          
    </div>

    </nav>



</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function ChangeSecondNavUlColor() {
    jQuery(".menu-secondary-menu-links li a").css("color","white !important");
    alert("Aasd");

}
```

Ideas why I'm getting this error and how to fix the issue?

**UPDATE 1 - ADDING THE FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
function ipe_resources() {
    // Add stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/default.css');

    // Add javascript
    wp_enqueue_script('script_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/ipe_script.js', array('jquery'), '2017', true );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ipe_resources');
```

UPDATE 2: ADDING THE HTML STRUCTURE - I THINK I AM NOT SELECTING THE A TAGS CORRECTLY??

```
<div class="menu-secondary-menu-links-container">

    <ul id="menu-secondary-menu-links" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-161" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-161"><a title="Our Programs" href="http://localhost/wordpress/courses/">Courses</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-160"><a title="Event Schedule " href="http://localhost/wordpress/events/">Event Calendar</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-159" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-159"><a title="Registration Open" href="http://localhost/wordpress/book-a-seminar/">Book A Seminar</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-158" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-158"><a title="Registration Open" href="http://localhost/wordpress/book-a-workshop/">Book A Workshop</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-293" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-293"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you loading your script? From functions.php or from your header?

Comment: I've added the file - functions.php wp_enqueue_script function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this line of code:

```
wp_enqueue_script('script_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/ipe_script.js', array('jquery'), '2017', true );
```

to

```
wp_enqueue_script('script_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/ipe_script.js', array('jquery'), '2017', false);
```

Changing true to false allows the script to be injected in the header instead of the footer.

For reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Another Solution would be to try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

window.onload = function() {
   ChangeSecondNavUlColor(); 
}

</script>
```

And for your script try this:

```
function ChangeSecondNavUlColor() {
    jQuery("#menu-secondary-menu-links li a").css({"color": "white"});
    alert("Aasd");
}
```

Comment: Have changed to above, still not working. Perhaps because the wp_head() is still called at the end of the header.php file? not sure

Comment: @Shaz I added another approach, and yes you need to call wp_head() before calling any script.

Comment: Perfect, so the onload function triggers only once the page is loaded correct? Also, the JavaScript is working however the a tags in the nav are not changing to color white... am I not selecting correctly in my func? I've added the html structure is question.. ideas?

Comment: @Shaz you are selecting menu-secondary-menu-links as a class, and its declared as an ID

Comment: Wow, okay the syntax - didn't know you put : and not , in .css({"color": "white"}). Thanks!

Comment: @Shaz Your .css functions was just fine, you can do both ways!